How to integrate SAP Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition?
I've been developing my project in VB.NET and reporting in Crystal Reports from years now.
Due to some issue or some other software installation which I don't have any idea of, my crystal report removed from VS2017 and now it is not integrating.
I've been using CRVS SP24 which is latest and last supported for VS2017.
Now the issue is I tried a lot of methods from internet like install using 'Run as admin', remove dlls and reattach, etc etc. but non of them working.
In my case I've a different issue. I cannot create a new crystal report .rpt file as there is no option in new item. Crystal report just vanished from new item option. And when I open my previous built files, I see hex code.
Irony is when I compile my project and give the exe to my clients, the reporting works like a charm there.
This is like I cannot create/edit a .rpt file because I guess the visual studio don't know how to open it as I found no integration.
Another thing I tried is I installed VS2022 in other pc and installed CRVS SP34 and it opens every file. Just some log4net issue which will be my 2nd question but the point is my reports opens there.
Help me with this.. What shall I do to see crystal report option in visual studio 2017??
